# How to stop automatic brightness change while on battery?

Tags: screen, brightness

I generally keep screen brightness lowest.While laptop is on battery  if I do not use mouse or keyboard for some time (I do not exactly know this time interval, maybe 20 second) brightness increases to some level between highest and lowest. Also if I use mouse or keyboard after this happens brightness becomes highest.This is very annoying. What is the solution if there is any?

Comment: I noticed that unchecking the `Dim screen to save power` option, and then setting a custom brightness, seemed to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

First, install `dconf-tools` with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`, then run `dconf-editor` to launch it.

Navigate to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`, and modify according to your needs, the relevant keys, namely:

```
brightness-ac
brightness-dim-battery
idle-brightness
idle-dim-ac
idle-dim-battery
idle-dim-time
```

Comment: in 14.04 there is no such a setting like `idle-dim-ac` and others. It seems to be a bug in Ubuntu, because the setting `Dim screen to save power` should be responsible for this, but it does not affect this behavior

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the comment. As you've noticed, Ubuntu evolves, and things change. The original question was not about 14.04, as it's been posted some three months before the development of Trusty got started.

Comment: sure, I know. I just wonder may be there is some way to fix this issue in 14.04. It is very annoying