# Screen brightness changes when moving mouse to certain areas (XPS13 9379 - Ubuntu)

Tags: 16.04, graphics, mouse, screen, brightness

When I move the mouse to certain areas, the brightness changes. Bright areas make the screen even brighter and dark areas make it even darker. 
This is really annoying. Does anybody know a solution?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on an XPS13 9370. Hardware is Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 and driver is i915_bpo.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out it is actually an XPS13 issue or "feature". On the 9370 it is possible to deactivate it in the BIOS:

```
Settings --> Video --> Dynamic Backlight Control --> Disable!
```

Comment: Glad you found it in BIOS.

Comment: In my BIOS it was called something like "Eco light". Some smart-a** marketing name for this artificial stupidity feature. It kept turning up and down the screen brightness when I scrolled through code in the code editor depending on how much text was on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's caused by [adaptive brightness](https://www.dell.com/community/General/Dell-XPS-13-9360-FHD-Adaptive-Brightness-Issue/td-p/5147488):

> 01-25-2017 07:40 AM RE: Dell XPS 13 (9360) FHD, Adaptive Brightness
>   Issue ?
>
> There is no "issue".
>
> The Dell XPS 13 9360 ships with a design feature called
>   "content-adaptive brightness control" (CABC). This feature will change
>   the brightness of the screen depending on the content that is rendered
>   on the screen.
>
> A number of customers do not like this design feature (me included, by
>   the way). As a result, Dell have made available a tool which allows
>   turning off / turning on of CABC ( [www.dell.com/.../DriversDetails](http://www.dell.com/support/home/ch/de/chbsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=PWD5K&osCode=WT64A&productCode=xps-13-9350-laptop&categoryId=AP) ).
>   This tool is _only_ available for systems with the QHD display, as,
>   apparently, the tool reconfigures the screen panel firmware.
>
> For the record: personally, I am very happy with CABC turned off on my
>   QHD display. I am also very happy that there is no dynamic brightness
>   control (reacting to environment brightness) is implemented either.