# Brightness dims depending on background

Tags: power-management, screen, brightness

I just bought a Dell Inspiron 15 5502 with i7 11th gen and Intel Irix Xe. It came with windows 10 home pre-installed. I installed Ubuntu 20.10 and completely remove Windows.

What I've noticed is that when the laptop is not pluged to power, the brightness dims depending on the background of the apps. For example, if the page that I'm navigating on has a dark background, the brigtness goes darker and when the background is white, the brigtness goes brigther. This stops when I plug the laptop to the power.

Does anybody has an idea on what's going on?

Comment: Something in the machine BIOS?

Comment: Yeah, check out this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005611/screen-brightness-changes-when-moving-mouse-to-certain-areas-xps13-9379-ubunt very valuable stuff there

Comment: See my edit: https://askubuntu.com/suggested-edits/175039

Answer (score 2):

You are facing a "feature", referred to by Dell as "dynamic brightness adjustment". This is actually a power saving feature of Intel graphics chips, but is also marketed that it increases your photo viewing experience. For dark pictures, the backlight intensity will be reduced, and contrast increased so you see more of the detail. Bright pictures will appear very bright in contrast with the dark content.

The battery saving is that for LED screens, displaying dark colors actually costs more power than displaying bright colors. In LED screens, there is a backlight that is continuously on. Dark pixels are created by blocking the light. That is never perfect, so that is why blacks on LED screens are not perfect. Creating dark pixels costs extra power to shield the dark pixels. For dark content, power saving is achieved by decreasing the  backlight (reduces power) and at the same time, darken pixels less (reduces power).

Admittedly, most will find this a hateful feature for daily use. It is, for example, impossible to do photo editing in such conditions.

**TL;DR**: Fix is here: [link](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-5502-laptop/inspiron-5502-service-manual/system-setup-options?guid=guid-bffa76a3-0626-42e1-9867-8ebfc7bda0dd&lang=en-us)

This is a feature of Intel Graphical chips. You are lucky that it only kicks into action when on battery. On other laptops, it is effective all the time. On some laptops, there is no way (and also for the manufacturer, no possibility) to disable it, on other laptops Windows drivers have become available to disable the feature.

You will have to find out what the possibilities are for your particular machine. It is unlikely you will be able to solve it from within linux. If you are lucky, you can disable it from within Windows after installing drivers from Dell. That will require you to (temporarily) install Windows again.

Nevertheless here is a excerpt from [this Dell support manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-5502-laptop/inspiron-5502-service-manual/system-setup-options?guid=guid-bffa76a3-0626-42e1-9867-8ebfc7bda0dd&lang=en-us). It is called "EcoPower":

> Table 4. System setup options—Video menu
>
> | VIDEO |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | LCD Brightness |  |
> | Brightness on battery power | Sets the screen brightness when the >computer is running on battery power. |
> | Brightness on AC power | Sets the screen brightness when the computer is >running on AC power. |
> | **EcoPower** | **Enables or disables EcoPower which increases the battery life by reducing the screen brightness when appropriate. Default: ON.** |

Use these manuals for your help!:

- [Entering BIOS setup program](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-5502-laptop/inspiron-5502-service-manual/navigation-keys?guid=guid-f448dd64-1b07-4857-a446-42e313a39cc8&lang=en-us)
- [Navigation keys](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-5502-laptop/inspiron-5502-service-manual/entering-bios-setup-program?guid=guid-dacdef92-bd0f-40c4-b280-5e81eb67a4c5&lang=en-us)
- [System and setup password](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-5502-laptop/inspiron-5502-service-manual/system-and-setup-password?guid=guid-70ac74a4-2716-4872-8f85-36cca0e01771&lang=en-us)

Comment: Last time this was asked I remember they found something in the BIOS to disable this.

Comment: @Levente Any model?

Comment: According to this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005611/screen-brightness-changes-when-moving-mouse-to-certain-areas-xps13-9379-ubunt It can go by the name "Dynamic Backlight Control", "adaptive brightness", "Eco light"